# htaccess make different page acting as home page

Tags: php, .htaccess

If user goes to URL

```
http://example.com
```

The server does a `302 Moved` and goes to `http://example.com/en/home/my-page.html`

What I want is if URL is

```
http://example.com/en/home/my-page.html
```

The browser should just show `http://example.com/en/`

I've tried with .htaccess like so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^en/home/my-page\.html
RewriteRule ^en/ /en/home/my-page\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ en/home/my-page\.html [L,R=301]
```

but it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can `RewriteRule ^en/my-page.html$ en/`

Comment: @Mohammad thank you, but does not work. will update the question shortly, forgot, didn't see before that page is in subpage..

Comment: which apache version you're on : 2.2 or 2.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex patterns are wrong.

You can use these rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# externally redirect /en/home/my-page.html to /en/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+en/home/my-page\.html[?\s/]
RewriteRule ^ /en/ [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /en/ to /en/home/my-page.html
RewriteRule ^en/?$ en/home/my-page\.html [L,NC]
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Still no change, I can still see `example.com/en/home/my-page.html` I've deleted cache and also tried with new incognito window in google chrome

Comment: Make sure this is first rule and there is no other htaccess in your system.

Comment: aah now something happens, I've put it to first line before other rules. (I'm using prestashop for the first time..) now it gives me error, but ok, .httaccess seems to work! thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code will redirect user hitting

```
http://example.com/en/my-page.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/en/
```

and than will internally redirect thr request to index.php (you can substitute  parameter with the directory where index.php is located or just remove it if it is in the main dir)

```
RewriteRule ^en/my-page\.html$ /en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en/ /<dir>/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Updated the question. Forgot to show that page is in subdirectory `../home/..`

Comment: Are your htaccess files enabled by the apache? Try adding some random invalid text in the htaccess and check if error is returned in the page.

Comment: Yes I get `Internal Server Error`